# Asymptotic solve question

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to find the asymptotic solution of the following differential equation-

```
In[1]:= AsymptoticDSolveValue[{\[Epsilon] y''[x] + 6 Sqrt[x] y'[x] - 
    3 y[x] + 3 == 0, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 3}, 
 y[x], x, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]

Out[1]= AsymptoticDSolveValue[{3 - 3 y[x] + 
    6 Sqrt[x]
      Derivative[1][y][x] + \[Epsilon] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, 
  y[0] == 0, y[1] == 3}, y[x], x, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

I thought it should be because of a lack of branch choice for $\sqrt{x}$. Is there a way around this?

Comment: x->???  Your syntax is wrong

Comment: I am not sure I understand where my syntax is wrong

Comment: For an asymptotic solution you must specify  x->.... Look up the help.

Comment: This is an asymptotic solution for epsilon to 0. Put this in mathmetica -- AsymptoticDSolveValue[{\[Epsilon] y''[x] + y'[x] + x  y[x] == 0, 
  y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1/2}, y[x], x, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]. There's no x->

Comment: I don't think you can series-expand this differential equation around $\epsilon=0$. Consider the solution for $\epsilon=0$: `DSolve[6 Sqrt[x] y'[x] - 3 y[x] + 3 == 0, y[x], x]` gives $y(x)=1 + C e^{\sqrt{x}}$, which has an infinite second derivative at $x=0$. Multiplying $y''(x)$ by any infinitesimal $\epsilon$ thus gives a non-small contribution to the differential equation.

Comment: @Roman the answer is an incomplete gamma function (can be solved analytically)

Comment: If y is a function of x and epsilon, you must write y[x,epsilon]

Comment: Please give the analytic solution if you know it, it may help with the analysis.